# Tomcat unable to start

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

When I am starting the tomcat-6, its giving me the below error:

> Error: Invalid com.sun.management.jmxremote.port number: %my.jmx.port%

I have enabled the remote port sometime back in catalina.sh startup file but I have reverted back, but still giving me the error and tomcat is unable to start. 
Is there any cache or something needs to be flushed which stops it to start the tomcat process.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how is the JVM launched?  Can you run `ps aux | grep tomcat` and paste the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
cd <tomcat-install-dir>
grep -r '%my.jmx.port%' *
```

Hopefully that will give you the answer.

Comment: I have already searched everywhere and its not uncommneted in any of the file. Thats the weired part. I have also even deployed the new tomcat installed the new java still the same error..